# Is there an hour and minute picker for jQuery?

Tags: jquery-plugins

Not a date picker,but should let user pick hour and minute,like `23:15`.

Is there such a plugin yet?

Answer (score 4):

My personal favorite is this one:

http://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker/

This works great and is really fast to work with - three clicks to set the time. And it's elegantly written, with code that closely resembles the jQuery UI date-picker approach and style.

It does minutes in 5-minute increments, however - not sure if that's precise enough for your purposes.

Answer (score 2):

I use [this one](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) in my last project and it worked like a charm. You can use it with both date and time at the same time or separately.

Answer (score 1):

check 10 jQuery Time Picker plugins: http://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-time-picker-plugins/

my favorite is http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

and this https://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker/

:D